# Laravel4: double post route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Sorry if can sound strange, but in the routes, on the post of my view I need to do two operations:

```
Route::post('booking', 'HomeController@booking');
Route::post('booking', function()
{
    return Queue::marshal();    
});
```

But of course doing this I get an error: Invalid data.

Yet for the post of the view 'booking' I need to call the method of the controller, and at the same time return `Queue::marshal()`

There is perhaps I can do this?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Here is the HomeController@booking method:

http://paste.laravel.com/19ej

Comment: Can you post your `HomeController@booking` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define two routes with the same verb and url, the second one is never going to be fired.

```
Route::post('booking', 'HomeController@booking'); // Laravel will find this route first
Route::post('booking', function()                 // so this function will never be executed
{
    return Queue::marshal();    
});
```

I see that your `HomeController@booking()` is handling a form. Why can you just use another route for this?

```
Route::post('booking/create', 'HomeController@booking');
```

And then change your form `action` method to point to this route:

```
// this will render <form method="POST" action="http://yourdomain.com/booking/create"
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@booking')) }}
```

This way you don't have one route overlapping the other.

---

Some advice unrelated to the question. Taking a look at your controller, I have noticed that you do this when checking for errors:

```
if ( ! $errorCondition) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // show errors
}
```

Your code will be a lot easier to read if you write it like this:

```
if ($errorCondition) {
   // return error
}

// do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you Manuel! It is working, but it takes quite a lot time, like 20 seconds. Is strange.
Probably because the form is uncomplete now.
I have made here another question regarding how to rewrite the form in sintax blade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120553/how-to-write-form-markup-in-laravel4

Resolving that issue probably will start to work smoothly everything.

Comment: Ok thanks to you i have arrived to the solution.
Your reasoning was exact. 
There was just a little issue that in this way it was sended 2 mails instead of 1.

So my solution in the end was this:

Route::post('booking', function()
{
 return Queue::marshal(); 
});

Route::post('rezervesana', 'HomeController@booking');

One is the english route, the other is the latvian route.
I still don't understand exactly how is possible, but doing this everything works fine. 
The queues are received from both and properly fired and the mails are sent in short time.
Thanks you for help!