# How to write form markup in Laravel4

Tags: html, forms, laravel, laravel-4

Can you help me to write this form tag in blade sintax:

```
  <form name="room"  id="1"  method="post"  class="narrow_width">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://laravel.com/docs/html for the `Form` syntax and methods.

You can wrap these in Blade tags.

```
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ Form::text('username') }}
```

Etc... In your case

```
{{ Form::open(array('name' => 'room', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'narrow_width', id => '1')) }}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
There was just a little issue regarding the id:

{{ Form::open(array('name' => 'room', 'method' => 'post', 'class' =>'narrow_width', 'id'=>'1')) }}